# Back arrow is closing drawer menu, not back

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I've got a problem. I've got a hamburger icon and back arrow too. Hamburger is working perfectly, but not the back arrow. It's working like a hamburger, opening and closing drawer menu.

Here is a code:

```
@Override 
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    hideKeyboard();
    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
}

@Override 
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    hideKeyboard();
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
}};

mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
pager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarInner);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openAndCloseDrawer();
    }
});

toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                openAndCloseDrawer();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

public void customizeActionBarWithBack(String string) 
{

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarInner);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000));
    toolbar.setTitle(string);

    setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
            customizeActionBar();
        }
    });
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    recreate();
                    customizeActionBar();
                    return true;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Where is a problem? Please help me guys!

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed` and call finish.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Where to put it? Cause i'm getting 'Method does not override method from its superclass' and also onBackPressed() never used

Comment: you can achieve this task using interface, implement interface in activity and define it in fragment then u can handle it by callback funtion

Comment: @DawidWalczyk is your activity extending AppCompatActivity? Or are you using a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dawid, you can also do it like as you are implementing navigation drawer in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

and other option to communicate with activity using interface, implement interface in activity and define it in fragment then u can handle it by callback funtion